# How to cast web method type

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-2.0

Hi every one I working on application that use web service.
To return a array of Images 
by this the method :-

```
[WebMethod]
public Image[] getImages()
{ 
    string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"G:\Images", "*.gif", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    Image[] myImages = new Image[images.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i <= images.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        myImages[i] = Image.FromFile(images[i]);    
    }
    return myImages; 
}
```

and in my application I try to use this Code for get this array

```
myWebServiceCalss sr = new myWebServiceCalss(); 
System.Drawing.Image[] imgs;
imgs = sr.getImages();
```

But system there is an exception

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'nameSpace.WebReference.Image[]' to 'System.Drawing.Image[]' "
```

How can I return this type from my web service.
Please any one can help me.

Comment: have you debug it, what is type of image is in WebMethod ?

Comment: If you hover over `Image` type in the file where the webmethod is, you'll notice that it's different than `System.Drawing.Image`, and I think that's what's causing the issue. Make sure the `Image` type in your webmethod file is `using` the correct library.